# OPENSSL command mistake

Tags: centos, openssl

```
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 3650 -in example.csr -signkey key.pem \
  -set_serial $ANY_INTEGER -extfile openssl.ss.cnf -out example.pem
```

This should generate a certificate.

```
openssl.ss.cnf:
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
subjectAltName =DNS:example.com
extendedKeyUsage =serverAuth
```

However, it says

```
usage: x509 args
 -inform arg     - input format - default PEM (one of DER, NET or PEM)
 -outform arg    - output format - default PEM (one of DER, NET or PEM)
...
```

What is wrong?

The command is taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Security/x509_Certificates "Self-Signed Certificates"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the command is showing you its usage help, it usually means you have an error in your parameters. What I do in such cases is look at the parameters one by one and check that they're present in the help.

In your case, you don't pass an argument to `-set-serial`; you should've replaced `$ANY_INTEGER` with an actual argument.

(Also: blindly copy-pasting commands from the Internet isn't safe, even if you're copying from MDN.)

Comment: Thanks! I got the certificate, however Mozilla doesn't accept it, as it's self-signed.